# Create MetaTrader Terminal 4 DLL file with C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, metatrader4

I learned C++ and I need to start creating plugins for MetaTrader Terminal 4 by coding DLL files, but I do not know how to start MetaTrader Terminal 4 programming.

Also I tried to look for resources or examples, but with no results.

Please I need some one to lead me how to start the tutorial and where to start.

Answer (score 0):

**For MetaTrader Terminal 4**:
Best start with the MT4 Help file and re-read MQL4 comprehensive documentation in built into the integrated MetaEditor IDE whenever in a need to re-check both the syntax and the conceptual features of the MQL4 code-execution units.

**For DLL side**:
Best start with any published DLL extensions, that were either published by third parties, or at least refer to the online documentation where **`#import <... > / #import`** section details all the starting points for successful design decisions in this direction of your interest.